# Angular JS Karma module not found

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I get an error message -"**ReferenceError: module is not defined**" when trying to test angular js code.

test script [testSpec.js]

```
describe('Project controllers', function() {
beforeEach(module('project')); 
describe('ListCtrl', function() {
    expect(1).toBe(1);
});
});
```

I have the following entries in my html file

```
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="angular-mocks.js"></script>
```

followed by my test script - testSpec.js

I specifically included angular.js and angular-mocks.js again. I get to see the following error message

```
Chrome 31.0.1650 (Windows 7) Project controllers ListCtrl should create 11 records FAILED
    TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'apply'
    Error: Unknown provider: ProjectsProvider <- Projects
        at Error (<anonymous>)
        at c:/Angular/angular-phonecat/app/angular.min.js:30:24
        at Object.c [as get] (c:/Angular/angular-phonecat/app/angular.min.js:27:310)
        at c:/Angular/angular-phonecat/app/angular.min.js:30:109
        at c (c:/Angular/angular-phonecat/app/angular.min.js:27:310)
        at d (c:/Angular/angular-phonecat/app/angular.min.js:27:444)
        at Object.instantiate (c:/Angular/angular-phonecat/app/angular.min.js:29:80)
        at c:/Angular/angular-phonecat/app/angular.min.js:53:80
        at null.<anonymous> (c:/Angular/angular-phonecat/app/testSpec.js:10:12)
        at Object.d [as invoke] (c:/Angular/angular-phonecat/app/angular.min.js:28:464)
    Error: Declaration Location
        at window.jasmine.window.inject.angular.mock.inject (c:/Angular/angular-phonecat/app/angular-mocks.js:1781:2
```

Here is the complete error

```
5) at null.<anonymous> (c:/Angular/angular-phonecat/app/testSpec.js:8:34)\n
   at null.<anonymous> (c:/Angular/angular-phonecat/app/testSpec.js:6:2)\n
   at c:/Angular/angular-phonecat/app/testSpec.js:2:1

Chrome 31.0.1650 (Windows 7) Project controllers ListCtrl should contain new fields FAILED
    TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'apply'
    Error: Unknown provider: ProjectsProvider <- Projects
```

Comment: could you show your `Projects` module?

Comment: I guess something is wrong with your `projects` module or you forgot to include it in the test

Answer (score 0):

I'm suspecting that you're missing some include files in you karma config file. Specifically, make sure you load angular.js.

Comment: yes - i have included angular.js, angular-mocks.js in my karma config file.

Comment: your post has changed substantially from the original question. can you post your testSpec.js file somewhere? Now, it seems you just haven't instantiated your modules properly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include **angular-mocks.js** ?
That should solve your problem.
You need that for it to work.